# an a get ajax get fail using nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

`i want to send an ajax get request to nodejs. (index.ejs -1.img) 
https://ibb.co/Hr61MDT

then i took the request in a nodejs file (index.js -2.img)
https://ibb.co/TR3W3N8
but right here

```
var limit=req.query.limit;
var start=req.query.start;

console.log(req.query);



Model.find({}, function (err, data) { 
res.render('index', { Bedirhan: data });
}).sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(start).limit(limit);
```

// skip(start).limit(limit);  // start and limit does not work
when we look at terminal (3.img)

https://ibb.co/749s8vP

`{ limit: '8', start: '0', _: '1559636568728' }`  this is good but

```
Model.find({}, function (err, data) { 
res.render('index', { Bedirhan: data });
}).sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(start).limit(limit);
```

this code does not work why

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your callback in a `exec` function

```
Model.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(start).limit(limit).exec( function (err, data) { 
     res.render('index', { Bedirhan: data });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Model.find({}, null, { skip: start, limit: limit, sort: { _id: -1 } }, function (err, data) { 
  res.render('index', { Bedirhan: data });
});
```

You should also handle the errors:

```
Model.find({}, null, { skip: start, limit: limit, sort: { _id: -1 } }, function (err, data) { 
  if(err) {
      //console.log(err) Your error handle
  } else {
    res.render('index', { Bedirhan: data });

  }
});
```

Using Promise:

```
Model.find({})
    .skip(start)
    .limit(limit)
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .then(data => {
        res.render('index', { Bedirhan: data });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        //console.log(err) your error handle
    });
```